# Changes to stage.displayState: Where's the event? (Flash, AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, fullscreen, stage

What event should I be looking for (on the stage:Stage, I suppose) to get changes to the stage.displayState?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this works

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.FULLSCREEN, doThisOnChange);
```

for both full screen and normal changes. In your `doThisOnChange` method, you can figure out which you're in by looking at `if (stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.NORMAL) {` etc....

Comment: How about the opposite? catching when the user exited full screen?

Comment: @whitehawk I haven't looked at Flash in a while, but I think that the doThisOnChange method fires on both enter and exit

Answer (score 2):

As long as your SWF is not embedded in HTML you should be fine. There are some additional hacks that you'd need to get HTML wrappers to work.

From the [documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=05_Display_Programming_10.html):

> You can use the `Stage` class's `fullScreen` event to detect and respond when full-screen mode is turned on or off. For example, you might want to reposition, add, or remove items from the screen when entering or leaving full-screen mode, as in this example:

Comment: Why are those docs under Flex docs? I never understood the structure of this stuff. But the Stage is common to Flash and Flex. THANKS for the answer.